# Adding JAVA to Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: java, eclipse, java-9, eclipse-oxygen

I already installed java jdk 9 and Eclipse Oxygen on my pc. I've also added jdk url in environment variable path and created JAVA_HOME variable. I ran cmd and entered javac command, everything went fine.

**1.**  Now, when I right click on a project > then go to Properties, I am redirected to Builders tab. I don't know where to add the JRE_SYSTEM_LIBRARY on my Eclipse Oxygen.

[image]

**2.** Also, when I want to create new project, by going to File > New, there's no suggestion to add a Java Project

[image]

**3.** When I go to Window > Preferences, there's no Java tab added below Install/Update tab.

[image]

Did I miss any step? Any help from you guys are much appreciated.

Comment: Its useful to add the version details in the question as well. Both java and eclipse.

Comment: There are many different "builds" of Eclipse. Are you sure you are using one that was tailored for Java work? In that "project" view - did you try "others" and had a look for "java project" there?

Comment: @GhostCat There are not different builds, there are different packages which are built by the same build. It is the Oxygen build (see question title or first section) and the [_Eclipse for Testers_](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-testers/oxygen1a) package (see the last screenshot). Does that answer your question, so you're [_happy to retract your downvote_](http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive)?

Comment: @GhostCat [_"Be welcoming, be patient, and assume good intentions"_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice). Your comment is none of that and your question has already been answered before you downvoted the question. _"happy to retract [...] downvote"_ is a quote from the website that you gave as the only reason. If that's technically impossible, you shouldn't blame the questioner for that. Sure, you should drop your downvote because the reason does not apply.

Comment: @GhostCat Either the wrong perspective is selected or JDT is not installed. The last screenshot shows this clearly. Promote what you love instead of bashing what you hate. I do not wait for my answer to be accepted. It's much nicer when an answer is accepted when you're not waiting for it.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have the [*Eclipse for Testers*](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-testers/oxygen1a) ([Jubula](http://www.eclipse.org/jubula/)) IDE package without Java support or at least you're not in the Java perspective (depending on the perspective, there are different menus). If there is no *File > New > Project...: Java > Java Project*, do one of the following:

- [Download](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/), install and **use an Eclipse Java IDE package**, e. g. the ***Eclipse IDE for Java Developers*** or the *Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers*
- **Install the [Java Development Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/) (JDT) into your Eclipse for Testers IDE**:

  1. ***Help > Install New Software...***
  2. ***Work with***: ***--All Available Sites--*** (or *`Oxygen - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen`*)
  3. In the list choose ***Programming Languages > Eclipse Java Development Tools*** and click ***Next >***
  4. After finishing the installation and restarting, switch to the Java perspective: ***Window > Perspective > Open Perspective > Others...: Java***

[image]

Comment: Where, depending on what the OP wants - it might make more sense to **throw** away this eclipse, and download a "pure java eclipse" thing instead. But that depends on what the OP actually wants to to achieve.