# Ant doesn't appear in Eclipse on OS High Sierra

Tags: eclipse, macos, ant, eclipse-plugin

I have a big problem and I don't found solutions on stack for the moment...
So, I try to install ant in Eclipse (v.4.7.0). I arrive to add it on my computer

[image]

but it doesn't appear in Eclipse
[image]

[image]

it's really blocking me, would someone have a solution?

PS : I hope my post is correct, it's my first, and thank you in advance.

Comment: Eclipse doesn't use any Ant that you have installed on your system, it only uses the Ant plugin installed as part of Eclipse. Some builds of Eclipse may not have the Ant plugin. Which Eclipse build did you install?

Comment: Ant tooling is part of _Eclipse Java Development Tools (JDT)_. See [how to get it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47391649/6505250). Note, there is a bug in Eclipse Oxygen: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46990633/6505250

Comment: @greg-449 I install  Oxygen Release (4.7.0)
Build id: 20170620-1800

Comment: @howlger thank's for the info !

Comment: There are lots of different flavors of install which contain different things.